# Find greatest low bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X have pdf:
$ f(x) = e^{-x}$ if $ x>0 $
     ($ 0$ otherwise)

Let Y be the greatest integer less than or equal to X. What is the pdf of Y?

Answer (score 2):

You have $Y=0$ if $0 \le X \lt 1$ so integrate the pdf of $X$ from one integer to the next.

Comment: It is not immediately clear to me what the pdf of X has to do with the pdf of Y when the relationship is between X and Y

Comment: It is in the first part of the sentence.  For any $X$, you round down.  The chance that $Y=0$ is precisely the chance that $X \lt 1$, so compute that.  That is the cdf of $X$ at $1$, or the integral I suggested.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks for your help